# How do I prevent Jsoup from removing 'href' attribute of anchor element?

Tags: java, html, jsoup, sanitization, html-sanitizing

I want to use Jsoup to cleanse input while still allowing anchor elements with an "href" attribute to remain untouched; however, I've found that no matter what I do, Jsoup.clean() removes the "href" attribute.  Test code follows:

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final String foo = "<a href='/foo/'>Foo</a>";
        final String cleansedOutput = Jsoup.clean(foo, Safelist.relaxed().addTags("a").addAttributes("a", "href"));

        System.out.println("foo: " + foo);
        System.out.println("cleansedOutput: " + cleansedOutput);
    }
```

The output of the code is as follows:

```
foo: <a href='/foo/'>Foo</a>
cleansedOutput: <a>Foo</a>
```

As you can see, the "href" attribute is stripped even when, as shown above, I explicitly tell Jsoup to preserve anchor elements and the "href" attribute (I initially used the default `Safelist.relaxed()` before adding `addTags()` and `addAttributes()`; they all removed the attribute regardless).

Am I doing something wrong?  Or is this a bug in Jsoup?  (It's hard to believe it's a bug, as their unit tests would have failed early on.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a documentation [Jsoup.clean(java.lang.String,org.jsoup.safety.Safelist)](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#clean(java.lang.String,org.jsoup.safety.Safelist))

> Note that as this method does not take a base href URL to resolve
> attributes with relative URLs against, those URLs will be removed,
> unless the input HTML contains a `<base href>` tag. If you wish to
> preserve those, use the `clean(String html, String baseHref, Safelist)`
> method instead, and enable `Safelist.preserveRelativeLinks(boolean)`.

```
String html = "<a href='/foo/'>Foo</a>";
Safelist safelist = Safelist.relaxed();
safelist.preserveRelativeLinks(true);
String clean = Jsoup.clean(html, "http://", safelist);
System.out.println(clean);
```

Will print out

```
<a href="/foo/">Foo</a>
```

Comment: THANK YOU!  This worked perfectly.  For what it's worth, I'm usually someone who reads API docs thoroughly, but this time I did not because I had used Jsoup.clean() previously without experiencing this issue, so I didn't think to read the docs again.  Perhaps this was a recent change, since my former usage of Jsoup was for a past version.

Comment: Note, that it might be necessry to add protocols. In my case, Jsoup removed `a` attributes until I added `safelist.addProtocols("a", "href", "http", "https", "mailto");`